# XSLT grouping on repeating element names

Tags: xslt, grouping

I have a flat source structure which needs to be grouped by following conditions:

The element P2 can occur many times after P1. The P1 and all of the following P2 elements till the next occurrence of P1 need to be grouped into a "Position" structure. The "Position" repeats when the next P1 element occurs.

Example of source:

```
    <P1><field1/><field2/></P1>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
    <P1><field1/><field2/></P1>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
    <P1><field1/><field2/></P1>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
```

The result should be:

```
<Position>
    <P1><field1/><field2/></P1>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
</Position>
<Position>
    <P1><field1/><field2/></P1>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
</Position>
<Position>
    <P1><field1/><field2/></P1>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
    <P2><field1/><field2/><field3/></P2>
</Position>
```

I am trying to use the axis following-sibling but cannot figure out how to select all of the P2 elements to the next occurance of P1. Or am I supposed to use the xsl:key in this case?

Answer (score 3):

In XSLT 2.0 it's a simple matter of `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="P1">
  <Position>
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
  </Position>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

In 1.0 the most efficient approach I can think of would be to define a key

```
<xsl:key name="P2key" match="P2" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::P1[1])" />
```

which groups P2 elements by their *nearest preceding* P1. Then process just the P1 elements and use the key to pull out the right P2s:

```
<xsl:for-each select="P1">
  <Position>
    <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('P2key', generate-id())" />
  </Position>
</xsl:for-each>
```

(personally I'd use templates rather than a `for-each` but `for-each` makes for a simpler example)

Comment: Hi Ian, that's great advice from you. I have implemented your idea and it works perfectly for me :-)